# Relationships in pony.orm with create_tables=False

Tags: python, database-first, ponyorm

The intention is to have two simple classes representing two related tables that already exist in the db.
The code is:

```
from pony.orm import *
db = Database()

class System(db.Entity):
    _table_ = 'some', 'systems'
    
    system_id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    structures = Set('Structure')

class Structure(db.Entity):
    _table_ = 'some', 'structures'
    structure_id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    system_id = Required(int)
    system = Required(System)

db.bind(...)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=False)
```

I've tried to follow the approach I've seen [in the documentation](https://docs.ponyorm.com/working_with_relationships.html#working-with-entity-relationships), but executing the code above gives me:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column structures.system does not exist
> LINE 1: ...ctures"."structure_id", "structures"."system_id", "structure...
>
> HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "structures.system_id".

What is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Pony, you don't create two separate attributes for `system_id` and `system`. Instead, you need to specify `system_id` as a column for attribute `system`. By default, Pony assumes that the column name is equal to attribute name. Then the `Structure` class will look like in the following example:

```py
class Structure(db.Entity):
    _table_ = 'some', 'structures'
    structure_id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    system = Required(System, column='system_id')
```